# set input value on new loaded form

Tags: jquery

I have this link that creates a few div's in which a form is loaded via load().
This form is in a separate php file. Now i want to use the ID value of my link to set the value of an input field, but how?

I know i need live() for that, but the setting of the value should be automatically, and not after an event.

It's a situation like below

**main.php**

```
[..]
<a href="form.php" rel="box" id="inputvalue">
```

**form.php**

```
<form>
[..]
<input type="text" id="el">
```

I now want to set 'inputValue' (when form.php is loaded) as the new value of $("#el"), but how?

My javascript file is in main.php and the way i load form.php is like this

```
$("a").click(function(){
 if(this.rel == "box"){
  [..]
  $("#container").load("form.php");
```

When the form is displayed i want to change the value of the input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provide a callback function which does exactly that. You can pass that as 2nd argument of [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

```
var linkId = this.id;
$("#container").load("form.php", function() {
    $(this).find('#el').val(linkId);
});
```

Note that it's a bad idea to have multiple elements with the same `id` in the document. Your code is namely suggesting that there are multiple links like that.

Comment: That's it! Thanks! Oh, and i won't have double ID's, no worries :)

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark the answer accepted (and do the same for the most helpful answers on your [previous questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/450454/maurice) whenever applicable). See also http://stackoverflow.com.faq.

Answer (score 0):

Provide a callback function to load which will execute once load is done:

```
$("a").click(function(){
 if(this.rel == "box"){
  var clicked = this;
  $("#container").load("form.php", function() {
     $("#el").val( $(clicked).attr("id") );
  });
```

Comment: If i use this method i will get <em>container</em> in the input value, because $(this) refers to that container, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `liveQuery` plugin, available here: http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs. It's a bit like `live()`, but instead of binding an event, it executes code for each matched element.

Comment: Will read it, but want to try fixing it myself without plugins, want to learn :)